# Unable to import executable jar file in the Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\ext folder

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

Am writing a java program using NetBeans IDE7.4 that will use the Player class found in **BasicPlayer.jar** file. i know of ways to include it in my classpath, e.g right click on the project > properties > libraries > add JAR/Folder.

what i want is to use the BasicPlayer class just like any other buildin classes in java without having to include the **.jar** file in every project.
so i tried this steps

- copied
  the **BasicPlayer.jar** file to **Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\ext** folder, and also **Program Files(x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_45\lib\ext** folder
- restarted my IDE.

after doing all that, i still coundn't see the **import** option on my Player class where i still get the **cannot find symbol: class Player** error when i place the cursor over the class object or even when i try to run the project.

is there any step(s) that am missing to do?

Comment: This is wrong on so many levels - and yet I'm interested whether it can actually be done.

Comment: i had tried before with JTatoo.jar and it worked!